# VBA ListBox and ComboBox display wrong characters

Tags: excel, vba, character-encoding, listbox

Excel VBA ListBox and ComboBox display wrong characters while TextBox provides the correct ones, using the same UserForm.

ListBox And ComboBox provides some Ansi substitute instead of Baltic characters, that is wrong.

I've changed:

- charset of form and listBox from 133 into 163 by using ListBox.Font.Charset property
- use of font Arial or Times New Roman with Baltic encoding
- read through tons of pages on the internet and still no luck..

Thanks for your attention

I used code as follows:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
UserForm2.Font.Charset = 186

ListBox1.List = Array("ĄČęėį", "Žųūįšų", 222) -> does not provide correct text :(

With ListBox1
.AddItem "Vilnius"
.AddItem "Kaunas"
.AddItem "Klaipėda"  -> Klaipëda
.AddItem "Šiauliai"  -> Ðiauliai
.AddItem Chr(222)
End With
```

Finally looks like VBA editor has trouble with international characters - if use button caption through Object Properties window - it goes wrong.

**But entering labels and button text directly on the form provides correct outcome, hence there is a work around here - use RowSource option, taking data from excel table, which gives right encoding:
ListBox1.RowSource = "=Sheet2!A1:A5"**

This solution is convenient to my needs and the question is closed by now.

Thank you for your response.

Comment: Please show the VBA code you use to populate those controls.

Comment: OK. Thank  you, here is the code: Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

NameTextBox.Value = ""
PhoneTextBox.Value = ""

CityListBox.Clear

With CityListBox
.AddItem "Vilnius"
.AddItem "Kaunas"
.AddItem "Klaipėda"
.AddItem "Šiauliai"
End With

DinnerComboBox.Clear
With DinnerComboBox
.AddItem "Vegetarinis"
.AddItem "Veganiškas"
.AddItem "Savo"
End With

Comment: Can you please edit your question, and include it there? Pasting code in a comment does not really work well on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

To populate ListBox and ComboBox with correct international characters I used Object Property window providing RowSource and taking data from Excel table.
In VBA editor it looks like this: ListBox1.RowSource = "=Sheet2!A1:A5"
Such an approach works well with Baltic and Russian languages, I did not try it with other languages.